# Django site-external access

Tags: python, django

A bit of a beginner question.Iv just started learning Django and can pretty much create basic stuff .Now when I want to access my website on my computer I just type in the local URL and I can access the site,other links etc.

If I want to show this to someone else how would I do it?..They wouldn't be able to just type in the local url so what would they need to do to access it?Also If someone asks me to create an API for them what exactly does it mean?I'm a beginner with web technologies so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You need a hosting provider to make your site public (Heroku, AWS, etc.). An API is an interface used by programmers to do something useful with your site.

Comment: have you deploy it on a web server like Apache? or wish to launch it on development mode via `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @Morteza Ipo..I have launched it in development mode using manage.py runserver..Heroku/AWS is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from doc:

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

```
python manage.py 0.0.0.0:port
```

And other machines on the network can view your development via

```
http://your_machine_ip:port
```

Answer (score 0):

By others, do you mean someone on your local network or someone on internet.

On local network its very easy, instead starting the local developmnet server by
`python manage.py runserver` you can do 
`python manage.py runserver 10.1.0.123:8000` (assuming 10.1.0.123 is your system's ip),

then people on you local network can access `http://10.1.0.123:8000` to see your site.

If you want to show it to someone on internet, then either you host it on something like heroku, or another cheap and quick method if to configure your router to divert the specific port to your machine and give that person your dynamic ip. This only applies if you have a router like in a home dev setup. You can go to google and just type what is my ip and get your dynamic static ip

Comment: ...I meant the interner-I guess Heroku looks to be the popular hosting platform.Thanks!